# How can I get disparity map and depth map from the feature matching result?

Tags: python, image-processing, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping, color-depth

I get a good result from the paper: [LoFTR: Detector-Free Local Feature Matching with Transformers.](https://github.com/zju3dv/LoFTR)

[image: result just like this]

Now I want to get a **depth map** from the feature matching result.

So I really hope that maybe someone can give me a link or code to reach this goal.
Thank you so much.

Comment: You first have to show as what you have done so far in your codes , then  others can have a look at it and help you.

Comment: I just use the open source code of this method and get the feature matching result of this two images. (for example pixel x=24,y=24 of the left image matches pixel x=20.3,y=32.5 of the right image ) I think maybe I can get the disparity result and the depth value of this pixel in the left image, so that finally I can get a sparse depth map.

Comment: Actually I am new to stereo matching and feature matching but my boss has this idea and wants me to realize, if it is too difficult maybe I will give up.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to achieve a reliable depth or disparity map using the feature matches, especially with the example you posted. A general algorithm to get you started on a low quality depth map would be:

- Find a rotation factor for one or both images that minimizes the sum of all of the y-offsets in the feature matches.
- Iterate through each feature and record the x-offset from image A to image B. This will give you a sparse disparity map.
- Now the difficult part... use an inpainting method (there are lots of them, look them up) to fill in the missing pixel values based on the existent values. (This would give you an unreliable result even if your initial images were well aligned, but it's your only option given your starting point.)
- Now you have a dense disparity map. Conversion from depth to disparity is a simple calculation but it requires knowledge of the camera's position, rotation, and properties (focal length, sensor size, etc) when each image was taken. You can make those values up in order to create a fake depth map, but again it will introduce even less accuracy.

Comment: Theoretically if I use bilinear interpolation to make the feature matching result ( sparse one ) into a dense one, can I get the depth map and disparity map?

Comment: bilinear would produce something like a dense map although it would only work within the region of the matches. Outside of the matches would just be a flat value.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand now.